# I am sending a parameter list say Medicine_name to an API, the parameter list will check the data base and return the values

Tags: sql, r, oracle

I am sending a parameter list say `Medicine_name` to an API, the parameter list will check the data base and return the values.

Eg:2

```
Medicine_name = {'A', 'B','C'…..}
```

`Med_Disease` table

**Medine to Disease table**

[image]

My query is picking only the 1st row using like command, not the other rows, I want all 1st, 2nd and 3rd rows consisting of A, B and C. I am using R and SQL(oracle).
P.N: No prior idea about how many tokens in that list can be.
Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is a query of what you are trying to achieve.

```
with your_data as (
  select 'A,B,C,D' medicine_name, 'D1' disease from dual union
  select 'A,C,B', 'D2' from dual union
  select 'D,C,A,B', 'D3' from dual union
  select 'D,A', 'D4' from dual 
),
split as (select distinct  regexp_substr(medicine_name,'[^,]+', 1, level) as medicine_name, disease from your_data
connect by regexp_substr(medicine_name,'[^,]+', 1, level) is not null),
aggr as (
select disease, listagg(medicine_name,',') within group (order by medicine_name) medicine_name from split
group by disease),
input as (select  distinct regexp_substr('A,B,C','[^,]+', 1, level) as medicine_name from your_data
connect by regexp_substr('A,B,C','[^,]+', 1, level) is not null),
aggr_input as (
select  listagg(medicine_name,',') within group (order by medicine_name) medicine_name from input)
select a.* from aggr a
join aggr_input ai on ai.medicine_name = substr(a.medicine_name,1,length(ai.medicine_name))
```

Just  substitute with `your_data as (select medicine_name, disease from med_disease)` 
and the hardcoded 'A,B,C' with your input parameter.

Let me know how it goes :-)

Comment: @ted-Thank you for your response but as I had mentioned my data set is dynamic it can be consisting of 3 tokens , 4 tokens or any number of tokens so what to do in this type of cases...

Comment: @KoushikRoy yes the code supports any arbitrary number of comma separated tokens

Comment: @KoushikRoy glad to be of help. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct.